# Drywall hanging orientation in residential home (walls and ceiling)

Tags: drywall

Good day. I recently moved to Canada and I have never really worked with drywall in my life. I am developing my small 500sq ft basement myself and I have done a lot of research on hanging drywall, but I am finding contradicting answers. I have one question for my walls and one question for my ceiling, if you could bear to read it.

With 24" stud spacing for walls, can I hang horizontal or do I have to go vertical? I have a drywall lift, so naturally hanging it horizontally would be easier for me. After some reading, hanging horizontal on 24" spacing seems asif it will create issues on the main seam unless I insert some form of backing. I had to cut the drywall into smaller pieces since my 180 degree turn in stairs down to the basement did not allow me to carry down 8ft panels. As such, I bought 12 foot panels and I cut the backing and folded them over into 2 x 6' sheets with the white paper in tact. Hanging these vertically (my wall is 8ft high) is a big pain now, because the cut portion that "folds" over is now only 2 feet and I put it at the bottom close to the floor. That means the 6' portion rests on the 2' portion at the bottom where the white paper stays in tact. I know its screwed to the studs so technically it does not rest on top of the 2' drywall but it makes me nervous.  I am not sure if it makes sense. Is vertical just the best way to continue since my studs are 24" apart? What do I do now that all my boards are cut into 6 foot lengths? Seems like my whole plan is falling apart.

For my ceiling, I am trying to figure out what parallel means vs perpendicular. English is not my first language, please forgive me. I bought 1/2" sag resistant ceiling board. Due to space issues I also had to cut them into 6' lengths. Do I attach the ceiling boards like the walls; Meaning I just run the length of the 6' sheet on the center of the joist? This seems like it will cause issues but I am not sure what I got myself into. I hope someone would be willing to explain to me.

Comment: Sheets perpendicular to the joists means the 12 ft edge of your unfolded sheet, or the 6 foot edge when it tears as you try to handle it is at a 90 degree angle to the joists.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to provide an extra blocking for the edge joints of drywall on 24" spacing. When the joints are properly taped with joint compound the sheets act as one. Which is to say, might as well go horizontal on the walls, it's going to be easier.

Incidentally, even if you do manage to not tear the face, what you have now is 6 foot long sheets that need a butt joint every 6 feet, because you broke the board there. Might as well cut them free and handle them that way.

Comment: The question scope includes ceilings. Since sheet orientation does matter in that case (from my memory of ASTM C840), it probably ought to get mentioned.

Comment: Tha k you for the answer. So even though the white paper for the walls are not torn, I have to tear it and ensure it ends on a center of a stud? Do I understand that correctly? Or can I just leave the white face paper and put joint compound over? Thanks again!